# Flag duplicate relationship in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data available in excel as given below:

[image]

Below is the criteria for the expected column:

> Duplicate relationship should be color coded/flagged.

> I have added expected result in a **column G** `Is duplicated?`.

To achieve that I have tried using `Match` function of excel, but it doesn't match my requirement.

Please suggest what should be the correct approach to fix this.

Comment: Why is the first element not a duplicate?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the formula as text and the data in columns A:D as csv.

Comment: @BigBen: because that is the first occurrence and that should not be marked to duplicate. Only the next duplicate should be marked. So I can pass the excel to data provider and they can delete the duplicate row there. e.g. in image - where 1st relationship is distinct, second relationship will be the duplicate to in that reference, so marking it will help to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a sorted csv of each of the words on each row:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,SORT($A3:$D3,1,1,TRUE))
```

[image]

| name | relation | name | relation | sorted_csv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Milly | Wife | Jack | Husband | Husband,Jack,Milly,Wife |
| Jack | Husband | Milly | Wife | Husband,Jack,Milly,Wife |
| Reacher | Son | Jack | Father | Father,Jack,Reacher,Son |
| Reacher | Son | Jack | Mother | Jack,Mother,Reacher,Son |

Then you can count the rows by sorted_csv:

```
=COUNTIF($E$3:$E$6,$E3)
```

[image]

| name | relation | name | relation | sorted_csv | count by sorted_csv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Milly | Wife | Jack | Husband | Husband,Jack,Milly,Wife | 2 |
| Jack | Husband | Milly | Wife | Husband,Jack,Milly,Wife | 2 |
| Reacher | Son | Jack | Father | Father,Jack,Reacher,Son | 1 |
| Reacher | Son | Jack | Mother | Jack,Mother,Reacher,Son | 1 |

Any row that has a count greater than 1 is a duplicate of another row.

Comment: That approach definitely looks achievable but unfortunately it looks like my license `MS Office Home & Student 2019` does not support this `SORT` function as it is throwing an error: `That function isn't valid.`